# Why do most people use the y axis as the up vector in xna?

Tags: c#, xna

Why is this?  I thought the z axis would normally be considered up?  Is there a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, it is an arbitrary convention. But here's how it arises naturally, and in OpenGL (not specifically relevant to XNA):

If you have a 2D image displayed on a monitor, it has X and Y coordinates and the Y coordinate is up (or perhaps down). If you have this 2D image be a projection of a 3D scene, then you gain a Z coordinate; keeping the coordinate transformation as simple as possible, Y is still up (and Z is outward).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of where it comes from.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are wondering why people choose this:

[image]

Over this:

[image]

It's purely a decision by the programmer. I'm sure the reason for the Y axis pointing up is just an extension of the 2D convention that the Y axis points up.

Answer (score 0):

It's all relative. I know of some games that use Y as up and some as Z. It's all up to the programmer and how they learned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that it has to do with the fact that in school every math book had the X and Y axis flat on the page and showed Z as a depth axis.

Comment: You had some unique textbooks. From Calculus on, we were taught that the Z axis is vertical, Y is horizontal and X is depth. Which always seemed to me, having an XNA 3D programming background, to be the most backwards possible representation.

Answer (score 0):

It's just convention.

OpenGL's default (identity) `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix is set to look forward -Z and +Y being up. It probably influenced developers, but it's all up to you. Actually recent OpenGL dropped fixed pipeline, and therefore the matrices, so this (technically) is no longer applicable.

I don't know DirectX's convention.